# How to display image which is saved in folder and how to return the path from controller to view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to display user image in profile page. I am storing image in folders.

My model class is

```
public string Imagepath {get; set;}
```

My Controller code is

```
var folderName = UserDetailsUtil.GetMemberPhotoPathFolderName(SessionData.UserID);                        
var fileName = SessionData.UserID;
var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Upload/MemberProfilePhotos/" + folderName), fileName + fileExtension);
imgfile.SaveAs(path);
ModelState.Clear();
```

How to return the uploaded image path from controller and display in another view ?

Answer (score 0):

In the most simplest terms, try something like:

```
return View("AnotherView", path);
```

Then in *AnotherView.cshtml*:

```
@model string

Your path: @Model
```

You'd be much better off using view-models though.